# Add headers to all requests in Swagger Laravel

Tags: laravel, swagger

I am using swagger with Laravel to document the application and I want to add 2 headers for all request and I am not finding how.

I have authorization with swagger:

[image]

and I would like that after the authorization set in all following requests 2 headers:

x-session-id: session seted in swagger authorization
X-Requested-With: X-Requested-With.

One of the request that it must have the headers is the following:

```
  /**
   * 
   * @OA\Get(
   *     path="/place/list",
   *     tags={"Lugares"},
   *     summary="Get places",
   *     @OA\Response(
   *         response=200,
   *         description="Get places list"
   *     ),
   *     @OA\Response(
   *         response="default",
   *         description="Has been occurs a problem."
   *     )
   * )
   */
  public function list()
  {
    $session =  session()->get('rismi2_session_data');

    $selDominioId = $session['sel_dominio.id'];

    $plantas =  $this->placeRepository->getPlace($selDominioId);

    return placeResource::make($plantas);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add `SecuritySchemes` to your API.

Link: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/

It must be used in your API declaration.

Example:

```
/**
 *
 * @OA\Info(
 *     version="1.0",
 *     title="API"
 * )
 *
 * @OA\SecurityScheme(
 *      securityScheme="XXX",
 *      in="header",
 *      name="YYY",
 *      type="ZZZ",
 * )
 */
```

Comment: Yes I added that in my baseController but then I have several endpoints and I need to set automatically for all endpoints the api-x header